# Sharing declarations between modules

Tags: flowtype

Let's take lodash as an example of a library that exports its functions across many modules.

Given the following imports:

```
import { flow } from 'lodash'

import flow from 'lodash/flow'

import flow from 'lodash/fp/flow'
```

The current `flow-typed` libdef for `lodash` exports only typedefs for the main lodash entry point which means our first named import gets type checked, however the latter 2 default imports do not.

We can create a new module for `lodash/flow` and declare the default exports for the `flow` function as:

```
declare module 'lodash/flow' {
    declare export default function flow(...funcs?: Array<Function>): Function;
    declare export default function flow(funcs?: Array<Function>): Function;
}
```

How can we extract these function declarations in such a way that we can share them across the main lodash entry point, the named `lodash/flow` module and also the `lodash/fp/flow` module?

Is there a way of creating/storing a declaration for use in many places?